# Java Google Sheets API get notes/links form cell

Tags: java, google-sheets

I need to read additional data, like notes(preferable) or link form a cell. Can't find such method in Sheets V4 API.

```
    var values = service.spreadsheets().values()
                        .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                        .setMajorDimension("ROWS")
                        .execute()
                        .getValues();
```

This returns me all the data in cells, but is there somewhere a method/way to get notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Instead of [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) you should use [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Specify `fields` to the values you are interested in, e.g. `sheets/data/rowData/values/note`

You can find the right syntax by inspecting the [Resource: Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#resource:-spreadsheet).